# accessing unions dynamically

Tags: c++, struct, enums, unions

I have this enumeration, union, and struct:

```
union num {
    int i;
    short s;
    float f;
    double d;
};
enum tag {SHORT, INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE};
struct vrnumber {
    num num;
    tag type;
};
```

I would like to know how to access variables inside the union dynamically based on another variable (i.e. the input of the user). (i.e.) I want to make a certain operation with the variables of the union But I want to know which union variable to access during runtime. so what would be a better way instead of something like:

```
vrnumber m; 
switch (m.type) {
    case SHORT: //an operation ..
    case INT: //same operation ...
    case FLOAT: //same operation ...
    case DOUBLE: //same operation ...
}
```

which I think is very lengthy and redundant while in every case it is the same operation only difference is when I access the union to store or use the value.

Comment: Reading from any member of a union other than the last one written to is undefined behaviour.  Can you explain why you want to use a union?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a [variant type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type). There are plenty of existing examples of this design pattern out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to define in the struct definition, the operators that are going to be used. For example, if operator `-` is going to be used, define these methods:

```
struct vrnumber {
    num num;
    tag type;

    //between vrnumbers
    vrnumber operator- (const vrnumber& rhs);

    //vrnumbers and basic types
    vrnumber operator- (const int& rhs);
    vrnumber operator- (const double& rhs);

    //if vrnumber is used as rhs
    friend vrnumber operator- (const int& lhs, const vrnumber& rhs);
    friend vrnumber operator- (const double& lhs, const vrnumber& rhs);
};
```

These are examples of the definitions of some of these methods:

```
vrnumber vrnumber::operator- (const vrnumber& rhs){
    switch(type){
        case SHORT:
            switch(rhs.type){
                //......
                //cases here
        }
        //......
        //cases here
    }
}
vrnumber vrnumber::operator- (const int& rhs){
    switch(type){
        case SHORT: return num.s-rhs;
        case INT: return num.i-rhs;
        case FLOAT: return num.f-rhs;
        case DOUBLE: return num.d-rhs;          
    }
}
vrnumber operator- (const int& lhs, const int& rhs){
    switch(rhs.type){
        //..........
        //...cases, same as the others
    }
}
```

Here are some examples of these operations put to use:

```
vrnumber m1;
vrnumber m2;
int i1;
float f1;
//the example:
m1=f1-(m1-m2)-i1;
```

The tradeoff of using this approach is the lengthy operator definition. However, if this kind of operations is called **A LOT** of times in the code, then this might shorten and simplify the code.